# Will JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject remove an element from arraylist when I run it

Tags: c#

I have the following code which deserialize an element from arraylist, I am not sure whether the DeserializeObject method will remove the element too from the arraylist when it deserialize it? Do I need to add recvJsonBuffer.RemoveAt(0) after each serialization?

```
                    List<Json> entities = (List<Json>)JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(recvJsonBuffer[0].ToString(), typeof(List<Json>));

                    foreach (Json obj in entities)
                    {
                        trace_idBuffer = obj.traceid;
                        plain_tagidBuffer = obj.Plain_tagID;
                        national_codeBuffer = obj.National_Code;
                        country_codeBuffer = obj.Country_Code;
                        res_codeBuffer = obj.Res_Code;
                        exp_codeBuffer = obj.Exp_Code;
                        reader_idBuffer = obj.Device;
                        data_sourceBuffer = obj.Datasource;
                        //  recvJsonBuffer.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't and if `DeserializeObject` does I would.... get very angry at the designer.

Iterating over a enumerable should be just that and not manipulating it.

Removing the element just like in your code with `RemoveAt` is also a bad idea.

It removes an item from the list/array you are working on, comparable to cutting the branch from the tree you are sitting on...

Why remove it? If you have no longer use of it let the GC get rid of it. Removing it wouldn't speed up the process but leaves everything open to shoot you in the feet (if you survived the falling_off_the_branch-thing)